# Initialization of Python program

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a Python program that stars with a bunch of code where I basically import some modules, initialize some variables and calls a few functions. Here's part of it:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.optimize as opt
import scipy.constants as const
import random
import time

if os.name == 'nt': os.system('cls')
if os.name == 'posix': os.system('clear')
rows, columns = os.popen('stty size', 'r').read().split()

Inclination = math.radians(INCLINATION)
Period = PERIOD*const.day
```

Is there a way where I can put all of this into once single module and just call it? I tried to put all of this into an external program and call it, but as I understood everything gets done, but only locally, not on the main code.

The idea would be to be able to also use this "initialization module" in multiple programs.

Comment: `from myInitializationModule import *` should work

Comment: Note that in general, masking what you are using like that is going to make your code harder to work with.

Comment: @Lattyware: This is a good point - 100% agree.

Comment: @Lattyware: Yes, I see your point, but since I also plan on use this "initialization" module in other places, I'd rather have it separated. Removing it also from the main program makes it harder to delete some of it by accident. Anyway it is still available, only in a different file. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try putting all of that into some other .py file, and then just `from x import *`? Then you should have all of those modules and constants in whatever file you called from.

**EDIT:** If you're worried about performing all of that multiple times, don't be. On an import, Python checks to see if a module has already been loaded before it goes and loads that module again. For example say we have these files:

fileA.py => from initializer import *
fileB.py => import initializer
fileC.py => import fileA, fileB

When you run fileC.py, the code in initializer.py is only run once, even though both fileA and fileB successfully load it, and even though they do so in different ways.

Comment: Hi Dave, no I just did a `import myInitializationModule`, thought it would be the same. Did this and worked like a charm, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need any special mechanism. when you import this module then python goes throw it and all values are initialized and you can use it. just import it and this is all.

Comment: I think he was trying to avoid the redundancy of the imports/initialization.  At least that's what I got out of *The idea would be to be able to also use this "initialization module" in multiple programs.*

Comment: @ pejot: I tried a simple `import x`, which did not work, had to do `from x import *`.

Comment: what about from x import *